# Ionic fab, pop up instead of drop down?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am working in ionic, and I have tabs placed at the bottom of the screen. I am using an ionic fab "right bottom" style but the tabs seem to block the drop down of the ionic fab. Is there a way I can make the fab list its elements upwards?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use [radio alert](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#alert-radio)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this its may be helpful !

```
<ion-fab right bottom>
    <button ion-fab color="light"><ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon></button>
    <ion-fab-list side="top">
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-facebook"></ion-icon></button>
      <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="logo-twitter"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-fab-list>
  </ion-fab>
```